# Perforce tkdiff

Tags: diff, perforce, changelist

Is there a way to do a `tkdiff` on two Perforce changelist versions of the same file?  In my previous job, where svn was used, I could use `-r` with `tkdiff` to get revision numbers.  For example:

```
tkdiff -r323262 -r314735 [filename]
```

That's not working in the Perforce environment.  Is there some feature like that with Perforce?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `p4 diff2 file1@rev1 file2@rev2`?

Comment: Thanks @paul-roub. This does help, but I was more interested in looking at the differences in the nice visual format that tkdiff provides.  It makes it easier to spot differences and debug.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  What worked best for me was p4v.  The Perforce Visual Client let me tkdiff between selectable versions of a file.

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the hash '#n' in the perforce file rev number and pass it to '-r' of tkdiff.

e.g. tkdiff -r4 -r5 filepath  will give you the diff between versions filename#4 and filename#5 .

Answer (score 0):

Using p4v is the best way to diff between two files, either by doing 'Diff against Have Revision', or starting 'Revision Graph' on a file, then dragging and dropping between the two revisions you want to diff.

In P4V you can stiff use tkdiff, by going into Edit->Preferences, then changing the Diff program to tkdiff,

[image: r]

tkdiff will then be used for 'Diff against Have Revision' or diffing between revisions in the Revision Graph view.

I used tkdiff in preference to P4Merge for a long time, until I discovered Beyond Compare.